# javascript function object and this

Tags: javascript

What's difference of this in the following two cases?

Case 1

```
var Person = function() { this.name="Allen Kim" }
Person.name; //undefined
```

Case 2

```
var Person = function() { this.name="Allen Kim" }
var me = new Person();
me.name // Allen Kim
```

Just wanted to understand how this scope works on both cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every function in JavaScript is itself an object. So `Person.name` retrieves the `name` property from the function itself, which was never set; hence `undefined`.

You can try this my setting it directly:

```
Person.name = "John";
Person.name; // "John"
```

---

When assigning a property from within the constructor via

```
this.name = "Allen Kim";
```

you're setting the property on that instance. When you then instantiate an object with:

```
var me = new Person();
```

your constructor will add the `name` property to `me`, since `this` referes to the object being created.

---

Here are the basic steps taken by the JavaScript engine when calling a constructor function with the `new` keyword:

1. Calls the constructor with `this` set to a new clean object.
2. Sets the internal `[[Prototype]]` property of your new object to the constructor's `prototype` (which, in some implementations, is then available through [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)).
3. Sets up the `constructor` property of your new object as a reference to the constructor function (so instead of the non-standard `me.__proto__`, you could access the prototype via `me.constructor.prototype`).
4. Returns said object.

<sub>Note that this is a very basic explanation. There are many other things not included here, but this should give you the gist of it.</sub>

Comment: thanks, can you describe what does 'new' do in javascript. I read http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/ and not very clear about it yet. I may have to read it again an again.

Comment: @bighostkim - That article you linked to is a very good article, but does not directly answer your question. I added a brief rundown to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

On the first case you are looking for a static property on the function itself.

The second case you are returning an instance of an object that has the property by calling a constructor function.  Its not really a matter of scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Person = function() { this.name="Allen Kim" }
Person.name; //undefined due to the fact that there is no Person object.
```

---

```
var Person = function() { this.name="Allen Kim" }
var me = new Person();
me.name // Allen Kim --> Person `me`'s name
```